# Rotating objects around global and local axis in bpy python

Tags: python

I have two sets of rotation data: Global rotation as `[x,y,z]` degrees AND local rotation as `[x,y,z]` degrees.

```
#eg.
globRot = numpy.radians([13,125,45])
locRot = numpy.radians([34,10,258])
```

How do I apply the rotations to a blender object in python... this is what I've come up with so far looking at other examples such as [Rotate object on local axis using a slider](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118057/rotate-object-on-local-axis-using-a-slider)

Is this correct?

```py
import bpy
import numpy
from mathutils import Euler

def get_rotation(obj):
    print(f"\nCurrent rotation: {obj.rotation_euler.to_matrix().to_euler('ZYX')}")
    return obj.rotation_euler.to_matrix().to_euler('ZYX')

def set_global_rotation(obj, value):
    obj.rotation_euler = value
    print(f"Global rotation was set to: {value}")
    return

def set_loc_rotation(obj, value):
    rot = Euler(value, 'ZYX')
    obj.rotation_euler = (obj.rotation_euler.to_matrix() @ rot.to_matrix()).to_euler(obj.rotation_mode)
    print(f"Local rotation added: {value}")
    return

globRot = numpy.radians([13,125,45])
locRot = numpy.radians([34,10,258])

obj = bpy.context.object

get_rotation(obj)
set_global_rotation(obj, globRot)
set_loc_rotation(obj, locRot)

print(f"Final rotation is: {obj.rotation_euler}")
```