# How do I rotate around local axis using python?

Tags: python, objects, transforms, axis

How do I rotate an object around the local axis using python?

Maybe something like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/188056/131649) answer.

Answer (score 4):

I found [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253872/rotating-objects-around-global-and-local-axis-in-bpy-python) question

and from it I got this:

```
import bpy
import numpy
from mathutils import Euler

def set_loc_rotation(obj, value):
    rot = Euler(value, 'ZYX')
    obj.rotation_euler = (obj.rotation_euler.to_matrix() @ rot.to_matrix()).to_euler(obj.rotation_mode)
    
obj=bpy.data.objects['Cube'];

set_loc_rotation(obj, numpy.radians([30,0,0])) #rotates by 30 deg on local x axis
set_loc_rotation(obj, numpy.radians([0,0,30])) #rotates by 30 deg on local z axis
```

Answer (score -1):

is that what you are looking for?

```
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].rotation_euler[0] = 1.5 # x
```